# Invisible CAPTCHA not working, most likely incorrect PHP?

Tags: php, forms, captcha

I am trying to incorporate an invisible CAPTCHA into my contact form, however I am not sure if it works.

My code is as follows...

HTML

```
<span class="test-field"><label for="test">Please leave blank</label>
  <input type="text" name="test" id="test"/></span>
```

CSS

```
.test-field {Display: none}
```

PHP

```
    <?php
if($_POST["test"]!=""){
    header("Location: {$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]}");exit;
}
// Get Data 
$f_name = strip_tags($_POST['f_name']);
$f_email = strip_tags($_POST['f_email']);
$f_message = strip_tags($_POST['f_msg']);

// Send Message
mail( "me@website.com", "Website Contact",
"Name: $f_name\nEmail: $f_email\nMessage: $f_message\n",
"From: My Website" );

?>
```

To test it, I did a few tests changing the...

```
f($_POST["test"]!="")
```

...to...

```
f($_POST["test"]="")
```

My PHP is not very good, but I am guessing this should not send the form through if the field is blank, but it does come through. Is there anything wrong with my PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what "doesn't work" means?

Comment: i don't really understand what do you mean by `invisible` if it is invisible why do you need it in the first place, and by saying it doesn't work, do you mean that you get some error or something else?

Comment: Sorry I have re-edited my post to make it more clear

Comment: @Adam Humor me please, Why would you want an 'invisible' captcha? Do you mean a 'hidden' captcha that will reappear on a user action?

Comment: Yes hidden captcha. I am just checking whether I have the correct code or not. The form above should not work if the field is not blank. I thought I could test it by temporarily changing the code so the form fails if the field is blank, which it is. But the form still sends, which us why I think the code is incorrect. Hope that makes sense

Comment: you don't really make much sense, but change your if to this `if(strlen($_POST["test"]) > 0){...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as your specific question it doesn't make any sense. A user CAPTCHA is absolutely useless if it's hidden.

The term CAPTCHA stands for ...

> Completely Automatic Public Turing Test to Tell Computers and Humans Apart

Notice it says humans ...

How can we test for human interaction if they can't see the CAPTCHA challenge? You Can't. Never-the-less .... here's a quick mock up of your code ... the CAPTCHA I left out since it make no sense. Take it from here ...

```
<?php

if ($_POST['test'] == "") {

    header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");


} else {

    // Get Data
    $f_name = strip_tags($_POST['f_name']);
    $f_email = strip_tags($_POST['f_email']);
    $f_message = strip_tags($_POST['f_msg']);

}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        #demo {

            width: 250px;
            height: 250px;
        }

        .test-field {
            display: none;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;

        }

        #form label {
            width: 50px;
            float: left;

        }

        #form input {
            width: 150px;
            float: right;

        }


    </style>

</head>


<body>

<div id="demo">
    <form name="form" id="form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
        <label for="test">Empty </label><input type="text" name="test" id="test"/><br/>
        <label for="f_name">Name</label><input type="text" name="f_name" id="f_name"/><br/>
        <label for="f_email">Email</label><input type="text" name="f_email" id="f_email"/><br/>
        <label for="f_msg">Message</label><textarea rows="15" cols="30" name="f_msg" id="f_msg"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="submit">

        <div class="test-field"></div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>

</html>

<?php var_dump($_POST) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have figured it out. My original code did work (and so does this), it was some javascript causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
if($_POST["test"]!=""){
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST["test"]) && $_POST["test"]){
```

Comment: Might as well throw some `error_reporting` in there while you're at it too.